# SSRS "Report Server Project" doesn't display in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have started working on SSRS and I have installed `SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition` and already installed `Visual Studio 2010`. When i am opening VS2010 in that case i didn't seen **Business intelligence Projects -> Report Server Project** but whenever i am opening **SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio** under **Microsoft SQL Server 2008** it shows in the new project wizard. My current project is in 4.0 and i have worked on that project using VS2010. How can `Report Server Project` show in VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 only uses a VS2008 shell. As Pratik says, you do need to use the SQL Server Setup and install the Business Intelligence Development Studio feature to install the VS2008 shell. You will not be able to use VS2010 to create your report server project until you upgrade to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav you need to install the business intelligence development studio also to see the Report server project templates.

See the same discussion on
http://forums.asp.net/t/1062316.aspx/1